# How can i disable till 1 week next future dates in Magento js Calendar?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, customer, calendar

I want to allow customer to choose dates after 1 week from current date.

Like as today date is 15 Feb 2019 so customer can select dates from 22 feb 2019.

I did change js for calendar by adding below code .

```
var calendarSetupObject = {
                inputField  : "' . $this->getId() . '",
                ifFormat    : "' . $displayFormat . '",
                showsTime   : "' . ($this->getTime() ? 'true' : 'false') . '",
                button      : "' . $this->getId() . '_trig",
                align       : "Bl",
                singleClick : true,
                 disableFunc: function(date) {
                     var now = new Date();

                if(date.getFullYear()   <   now.getFullYear())  { return true; }
                if(date.getFullYear()   ==  now.getFullYear())  { if(date.getMonth()    <   now.getMonth()) { return true; } }
                if(date.getMonth()      ==  now.getMonth())     { if(date.getDate()     <   now.getDate()+7)  { return true; } }
                 }

            }
```

so now its displaying same calendar what i want but its not allowing me select date 22 feb now .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
disableFunc: function(date) {
            var now = new Date();
            var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
            // disable all previous dates...
            if(date.getFullYear()   <   now.getFullYear())  { return true; }
            if(date.getFullYear()   ==  now.getFullYear())  { if(date.getMonth()    <   now.getMonth()) { return true; } }
            if(date.getMonth()      ==  now.getMonth())     { if(date.getDate()     <=   now.getDate())  { return true; } }
             }
            // disable next 7 days...
            if(((date.getTime() - now.getTime())/one_day) <= 7){ return true; }
```